# What causes error "The type of the expression in the let clause is incorrect."

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods, monads

I have implemented a State monad, and am working on enabling LINQ "Comprehension Syntax" with extension methods.

Can anyone provide insight on the cause of the error in the title? Perhaps an extension method is missing, or one has the wrong signature. It is puzzling that the more detailed aspects of LINQ work, and something seemingly as trivial as the `let` clause isn't.

Please note: There are numerous posts elsewhere on similar sounding errors in regards to the "select" or "join" clause; I have not been able to discern any similarity to my case below.

This example compiles and runs correctly:

```
namespace StateMonad {
  using StateUnit = State<Unit,GCDState>;
  using TupleUnit = State<Unit,GCDState>.StateTuple;

  private static class TestClass  {

    // This usage compiles and runs fine.
    private static readonly StateUnit GcdInner_Good =
      ( from s in State<Unit,GCDState>.Get
        select new TupleUnit(Unit.unit, 
              s.A > s.B ? new GCDState(s.B, s.A-s.B)
            : s.A < s.B ? new GCDState(s.B,   s.A  )
                        : s)
      );
// continued below
```

But this one does not, generating the error of interest on the first `let`:

```
// continued from above  

    // This usage fails to compile, with error as shown
    private static readonly StateUnit GcdInner_Bad =
      ( from s in State<Unit,GCDState>.Get
        let A = s.A       // Generates error on "let":
        let B = s.B       //   "The type of the expression in the let clause is incorrect.
                          //    Type inference failed in the call to 'Select'."
        select new TupleUnit(Unit.unit, 
              A > B ? new GCDState(B, A - B)
            : A < B ? new GCDState(B,   A  )
                        : s)
      );
  }
}
```

Here are the Extension methods declared so far:

```
  public static class StateExtensions {
    [Pure]public static State<TResult,TState>    Select<TValue,TState,TResult>( this
      State<TValue,TState> @this,
      Func<TValue,State<TResult,TState>.StateTuple> projector
    ) where TResult:struct where TState:struct where TValue:struct {
      projector.ContractedNotNull("projector");

      return new State<TResult,TState>(s => projector(@this.EvalState(s)));
    }

    [Pure]public static State<TResult,TState>    SelectMany<TValue,TState,TResult>( this
        State<TValue,TState> @this,
        Func<TValue,State<TResult,TState>> selector
    ) where TResult:struct where TState:struct where TValue:struct {
        selector.ContractedNotNull("selector");

        return @this.Bind(selector);
    }

    [Pure]public static State<TResult,TState>   SelectMany<TValue,TState,T,TResult>( this
        State<TValue,TState> @this,
        Func<TValue, State<T,TState>> selector,
        Func<TValue, T, TResult> projector
    ) where TResult:struct where TState:struct where TValue:struct where T:struct {
        selector.ContractedNotNull("selector");
        projector.ContractedNotNull("projector");

        return new State<TResult, TState>(s => {
            var value = @this.RunState(s).Value;
            return new State<TResult, TState>.StateTuple(
                projector(value, selector(value).RunState(s).Value) ,s);
        } );    
    }
  }
```

And here are the essentials of the State monad class:

```
  public struct State<TValue,TState> : IEquatable<State<TValue,TState>>
  where TValue:struct where TState:struct {
    public delegate StateTuple Transformer(TState state);

    public State(Transformer transformer) : this() {
        Contract.Requires(transformer != null);
        _transformer = transformer;
    }

    [Pure]public State<TResult,TState>    Bind<TResult> (
      Func<TValue, State<TResult,TState>> selector
    ) where TResult:struct {
        selector.ContractedNotNull("selector");

        var @this = this;
        return new State<TResult,TState>(state => {
            var tuple = @this.RunState(state);
            return selector(tuple.Value).RunState(tuple.State);
        } );
    }

    [Pure]public StateTuple   RunState(TState state)  { return _transformer(state); }
    [Pure]public TValue       EvalState(TState state) { return RunState(state).Value; }
    [Pure]public TState       ExecState(TState state) { return RunState(state).State; }

    private readonly Transformer _transformer;
  }


public struct StateTuple {
  public StateTuple(Tuple<TValue, TState> content) : this(content.Item1,content.Item2) {
      content.ContractedNotNull("content");
  }
  public StateTuple(TValue value, TState state ) : this() {
      _value = value; _state = state;
  }
  public TValue Value { get {return _value;} } readonly TValue _value;
  public TState State { get {return _state;} } readonly TState _state;

  #region Value Equality with IEquatable<T>.
  /// <inheritdoc/>
  [Pure]public override bool Equals(object obj) { 
    var other = obj as StateTuple?;
    return other != null  &&  other.Equals(obj);
  }

  /// <summary>Tests value-equality, returning <b>false</b> if either value doesn't exist.</summary>
  [Pure]public bool Equals(StateTuple other) {
    return this.Value.Equals(other.Value)  &&  this.State.Equals(other.State);
  }

  /// <inheritdoc/>
  [Pure]public override int GetHashCode() { unchecked { return Value.GetHashCode() ^ State.GetHashCode(); } }

  /// <inheritdoc/>
  [Pure]public override string ToString() {
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<string>() != null);
    return String.Format("({0},{1})",Value,State);
  }

  /// <summary>Tests value-equality, returning <b>false</b> if either value doesn't exist.</summary>
  [Pure]public static bool operator == (StateTuple lhs, StateTuple rhs) { return lhs.Equals(rhs); }

  /// <summary>Tests value-inequality, returning <b>false</b> if either value doesn't exist..</summary>
  [Pure]public static bool operator != (StateTuple lhs, StateTuple rhs) { return ! lhs.Equals(rhs); }
  #endregion
}
```

Here is some more utilities needed to compile:

```
  /// <summary>TODO</summary>
  public static class State {
    public static State<bool,TState>            DoWhile<TState>( this
        State<bool,TState>.Transformer body
    ) where TState:struct {
        return new State<bool,TState>(state => {
            State<bool,TState>.StateTuple tuple;
            do { tuple = body(state); state = tuple.State; } while (tuple.Value);
            return tuple;
        } );
    }

    /// <summary>Implements the Haskell operator (liftM): liftM f m = m >>= (\x -> return (f x))</summary>
    public static State<B,TState> LiftM<TState,A,B>( this
        State<A,TState> @this,
        Func<A,B> func
    ) where TState:struct where A:struct where B:struct {
        return @this.Bind(t => new State<B,TState>(s => new State<B,TState>.StateTuple(func(t),s)) );
    }
  }

  /// <summary>TODO</summary>
  public static class State<TState> where TState:struct {
    public readonly static State<TState, TState>    Get
        = new State<TState, TState>(s => new State<TState,TState>.StateTuple(s, s));
    public          static State<Unit,TState>       Put(TState state) {
        return new State<Unit,TState>( s => new State<Unit,TState>.StateTuple(Unit.unit,state) );
    }

    #region Convenience extensions to Get() for efficiency
    /// <summary>TODO</summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TValue"></typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TState"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="selector"></param>
    [Pure]public static State<TValue,TState>   GetBind<TValue>(
        Func<TState, State<TValue,TState>> selector
    ) where TValue:struct {
        selector.ContractedNotNull("selector");

        return new State<TValue,TState>( s => selector(s).RunState(s) );
    }

    /// <summary>TODO</summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TValue"></typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TState"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="selector"></param>
    [Pure]public static State<TValue,TState>   GetCompose<TValue>(
        Func<TState,State<TValue,TState>> selector
    ) where TValue:struct {
        selector.ContractedNotNull("selector");

        return new State<TValue,TState>( s => selector(s).RunState(s) );
    }

    /// <summary>TODO</summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TValue"></typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TState"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="selector"></param>
    [Pure]public static State<Unit,TState>    GetComposePut(
        Func<TState,TState> transform
    ) {
        transform.ContractedNotNull("transform");

        return new State<Unit,TState>( s => new State<Unit,TState>.StateTuple(Unit.unit,transform(s)) );
    }

    /// <summary>TODO</summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TValue"></typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TState"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="selector"></param>
    [Pure]public static State<TValue,TState>   GetSelect<TValue>(
        State<TValue,TState>.Transformer projector
    ) where TValue:struct {
        projector.ContractedNotNull("projector");

        return new State<TValue,TState>(projector);
    }
    #endregion
  }
```

Comment: @Codexer Don't think so; I have an example now in my code that still fails compilation when I replace the lambda with a static function. Likewise when I leave the usage in the lambda as field references to `s`.

Comment: This is all very mind boggling, but I might be able to offer some insight if I could get it to compile.  I can't find a declaration of StateTuple anywhere.  Is it safe to keep adding declarations until it builds?

Comment: Where's the definition of `State<T, S>.Get`? A lot of definitions are missing to get this to compile.

Comment: @recursive: `StructTuple` code added. I haven't pared it down to a bare minimum. I believe it would be fine to add dummies of anything I have inadvertently omitted.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: Thanks for the updates, although the new additions have their own compilation problems, like `StateTuple` refers to some undeclared generic parameters.  I'm going to make some educated assumptions.

Comment: @Lee: Added code for the the two subsidiary classes `State` and `State<TState>`.

Comment: @recursive - `StateTuple` is a nested class inside `State<T, S>` I think.

Comment: Ok, I'm making some progress, but `State<Unit,GCDState>.Get` has no declaration, and I don't think I can make up a plausible guess for what that's supposed to return.  I'm assuming it's an `IEnumerable<Something>` where `Something` has a `.A` and `.B` property, of some type that declares a subtraction operator.  I will admit I don't understand the state monad, or what a monad even is in the first place, but I think you're going to need to provide a working reproduction of the problem before anyone can help.

Comment: @recursive; It is just a convenience property in `State<TValue,TState>`: `[Pure]public static State<TState, TState>  Get { get { return State<TState>.Get;} }`

Comment: I give up.  Your convenience property `Get` refers to a type `State<T>` with a single generic paramter.  Is that a typo?  There's a single `State` declared in your example code, but it requires two generic parameters.

Comment: @recursive: Check my latest edit; I added the full code for the two static auxiliary classes `State` and `State<TState>`.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: Thanks.  At this point, I think it's highly unlikely I'll ever comprehend this, but it's a fun exercise.  I may continue trying to get it to build just for the challenge.

Answer (score 2):

I think your definition of `Select` is the problem. It should have type `State<T, S> -> Func<T, R> -> State<R, S>` i.e. it should only operate on the result type, not the state. If you add an instance method with that signature:

```
public State<TResult, TState> Select<TResult>(Func<TValue, TResult> selector)
{
    Transformer t = this._transformer;
    var inner = new State<TResult, TState>.Transformer(s =>
    {
        var inter = t(s);
        return new State<TResult, TState>.StateTuple(selector(inter.Value), inter.State);
    });
    return new State<TResult, TState>(inner);
}
```

Note the above definition requires the `struct` restrictions (which should not be necessary) from the `TState` and `TResult` parameters of the State type.

and then fix the type of your state expressions:

```
private static readonly State<TupleUnit, GCDState> GcdInner_Good =
      (from s in State<Unit, GCDState>.Get
       select new TupleUnit(Unit.unit,
             s.A > s.B ? new GCDState(s.B, s.A - s.B)
           : s.A < s.B ? new GCDState(s.B, s.A)
                       : s)
      );

        private static readonly State<TupleUnit, GCDState> GcdInner_Bad =
      (from s in State<Unit, GCDState>.Get
       let A = s.A
       let B = s.B
       select new TupleUnit(Unit.unit,
             A > B ? new GCDState(B, A - B)
           : A < B ? new GCDState(B, A)
                       : s)
      );
```

then they will both type check.

A query expression containing a `let` clause like

```
from s in src
let x = s.Expr
select x
```

will be converted into:

```
src.Select(s => new { S = S, X = s.Expr }).Select(s => s.X);
```

and the compiler is failing to infer the type of the intermediate `Select` call. This is probably because it is an extension method and contains an unused type parameter. If you make it an instance method you can remove this ambiguity.

The following implementation of `State` supports using `let` inside the query syntax:

```
public class State<TState, TResult>
{
    private readonly Func<TState, StateResult<TState, TResult>> f;

    public State(Func<TState, StateResult<TState, TResult>> f)
    {
        this.f = f;
    }

    public StateResult<TState, TResult> Run(TState state)
    {
        return this.f(state);
    }

    public TResult RunResult(TState state)
    {
        return this.f(state).Result;
    }

    public TState RunState(TState state)
    {
        return this.f(state).State;
    }

    public State<TState, TOut> Select<TOut>(Func<TResult, TOut> mapFunc)
    {
        Contract.Requires(mapFunc != null);

        return new State<TState, TOut>(s =>
        {
            var thisResult = this.f(s);
            return new StateResult<TState, TOut>(s, mapFunc(thisResult.Result));
        });
    }

    public State<TState, TOut> BiSelect<TOut>(Func<StateResult<TState, TResult>, StateResult<TState, TOut>> mapFunc)
    {
        return new State<TState, TOut>(s =>
        {
            return mapFunc(this.f(s));
        });
    }

    public State<TState, TOut> SelectMany<TOut>(Func<TResult, State<TState, TOut>> bindFunc)
    {
        return SelectMany(bindFunc, (_, r) => r);
    }

    public State<TState, TOut> SelectMany<TInter, TOut>(Func<TResult, State<TState, TInter>> bindFunc, Func<TResult, TInter, TOut> selector)
    {
        return new State<TState, TOut>(initialState =>
        {
            var thisResult = this.f(initialState);
            var nextState = bindFunc(thisResult.Result);
            var nextResult = nextState.Run(thisResult.State);
            var result = selector(thisResult.Result, nextResult.Result);
            return new StateResult<TState, TOut>(nextResult.State, result);
        });
    }
}

public static class State
{
    public static State<TState, TResult> FromResult<TState, TResult>(TResult result)
    {
        return new State<TState, TResult>(s => new StateResult<TState, TResult>(s, result));
    }

    public static State<TState, TState> Get<TState>()
    {
        return new State<TState, TState>(s => new StateResult<TState, TState>(s, s));
    }

    public static State<TState, Unit> Put<TState>(TState state)
    {
        return new State<TState, Unit>(_ => new StateResult<TState, Unit>(state, Unit.Instance));
    }

    public static State<TState, Unit> Modify<TState>(Func<TState, TState> modifyFunc)
    {
        return from s in Get<TState>()
               from _ in Put(modifyFunc(s))
               select Unit.Instance;
    }
}

public struct StateResult<TState, TResult>
{
    public StateResult(TState state, TResult result)
        : this()
    {
        this.State = state;
        this.Result = result;
    }

    public TState State { get; private set; }
    public TResult Result { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Interesting thought line; but I cannot (yet at least) determine how to implement the State monad semantics for **Select** with that type signature. I originally had all three extension methods set up similarly to this, but had to move towards what I now have to get the *from* and *select* clauses for LINQ to compile and run; this seems to be a regression, but I will chase it a bit further tonight.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - I updated the answer with an implementation for `Select`.

Comment: You got some details incorrect, particularly as the existing `Select` is used elsewhere for LINQ, but a second implementation is required with this signature: `public static State<TResult,TState>       Select<TValue,TState,TResult>( this
      State<TValue,TState> @this,
      Func<TValue, TResult> projector
    )`. However that new gives me a new error: "*The type 'AnonymousType#1' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter TResult in the generic type or method '... Select( ... System.Func<TValue, TResult>)'*".

Comment: If you are not getting that error it may be to me still being on VS 2013 and Framework 4.5. This is progress, but I may have to live with the inability to use `let` for now.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - Sorry, you don't need the `struct` constraint on `TResult` in `Select`, see update. You also need to remove the struct constraints on `TState` and `TValue` in the definition of `State`.